# SSO with SiteMinder for CXF SOAP implementation from http client(command line)

Tags: java, soap, cxf, single-sign-on, siteminder

I need to access a soap service developed with CXF which is protected by CA siteminder from a command line http client. My question is:

1. Can "JAX-RS: SAML Web SSO" which in cXF document be leveraged for SOAP service?
2. How a command line http client interact with IDP for login?